# Пытаюсь адаптировать порядок блоков

Tags: css, flexbox

Хочу сделать так, что бы блоки не стакались в 1 линии, а продолжали порядок на следующей линии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#updates_container {
  display: flex;
}

.updates_new {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 12em;
  height: 15em;
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="updates_container">
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#updates_container {
  display: flex;
  /* в строку с переносом */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* центрирование */
  justify-content: center;
}

.updates_new {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 12em;
  height: 15em;
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="updates_container">
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="updates_new">
    <p class="updates_text_top">
      Title for updates
    </p>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_center">
      On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute
      men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.
    </div>
    <div class="updates_line"></div>
    <div class="updates_text_bottom">
      Bottom for updates
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогли